# AWS Step Function: error occurred (404) when calling the CreateStateMachine operation: PathNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to test AWS State Machine and Lambda function by following [Step Functions and AWS SAM CLI Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-local-lambda.html)

The Lambda is running on local docker container as expected, and I can get proper result after invoke lambda function with command `aws lambda invoke --function-name`
The step function is running as expected as well.

The Lambda and Step function is up and running at local, but got following error when start State machine which reference SAM CLI Local Function.

```
An error occurred (404) when calling the CreateStateMachine operation: PathNotFoundException
```

Also seeing following message from lambda function terminal when started state machine:

```
2022-11-09 13:02:35 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2022 13:02:35] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

**Following are some partial code and command for this test.**

Partial code in template.yaml from Lambda function

```
Resources:
  TestLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
```

Step function local setting file(sf-setting-local.txt)

```
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=123456789012
LAMBDA_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:3001
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxxx
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
```

state machine file:(state_machine.json)

```
{
  "Comment": "An example of the Amazon States Language using an AWS Lambda Local function",
  "StartAt": "LambdaDocker",
  "States": {
    "LambdaDocker": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:TestLambda",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Command to create State Machine:

```
aws stepfunctions --endpoint-url "http://127.0.0.1:3001" create-state-machine --definition file://state_machine.json --name "TestLambda" --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/DummyRole"
```

What could cause this PathNotFoundException error? Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: You are calling the Step Functions service on the Lambda service's port (`3001`).  If you are following the tutorial step-by-step, your Step Functions docker endpoint will be at port `8083`.

Answer (score 0):

There 2 things I have to correct to make this test work:

1. Change the endpoint-url in the command to create State Machine from http://127.0.0.1:3001 to http://localhost:8083
2. Change the LAMBDA_ENDPOINT=http://host.docker.internal:3001 in step function local setting file.